# background music button change image if on/off

Tags: ios, objective-c, avaudioplayer

AppDelegate.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{

AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
}

- (void) playPauseBackgroundMusic;

@end
```

.m

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

NSString *backgroundMusicString =[[NSBundle mainBundle]pathForResource:@"backgroundmusic" ofType:@"mp3"];
backgroundMusic = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:backgroundMusicString] error:nil];
backgroundMusic.delegate=self;
backgroundMusic.numberOfLoops=-1;
backgroundMusic.volume=0.2;
[backgroundMusic play];

return YES;
}

- (void) playPauseBackgroundMusic {

if ([backgroundMusic isPlaying]) {
    [backgroundMusic pause];
}else{
    [backgroundMusic play];
}

}
```

Works fine, background music in all views. I want now to turn on/off the music, so i have this button in all views:

.h (other viewcontroller)

```
- (IBAction)backgroundMusicOnOff:(id)sender;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *backgroundMusicOnOff;
```

.m (other viewcontroller)

```
- (IBAction)backgroundMusicOnOff:(id)sender {

AppDelegate *theDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

[theDelegate playPauseBackgroundMusic];
}
```

is also working. But i want that my image of my button changes, if backgroundmusic is playing i want that all my buttons display the image "sound_on.png" and if the backgroundmusic is pause i want to show the image "sound_off.png"

tried with

```
if (theDelegate.backgroundMusic.isplaying) {

    UIImage * btnImage1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_on.png"];
    [_backgroundMusicOnOff setImage:btnImage1 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}else{

    UIImage * btnImage2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"sound_off.png"];
    [_backgroundMusicOnOff setImage:btnImage2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

but it doesn't work.

thanks for helping!

Comment: where is that last code section located? I would put it right after `[theDelegate playPauseBackgroundMusic];` You say it doesn't work, but what happens specifically?

Answer (score 0):

solved my problem with @public in my AppDelegate.h, @protected is default...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>{
@public
AVAudioPlayer *backgroundMusic;
}

- (void) playPauseBackgroundMusic;

@end
```